# WebRequest time out error

Tags: windows, mono, timeout, webrequest

I tried to build an application in Mono using the setting "Mono 2.10.2", but the the following errors.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00046] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\System\System.Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:813
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in C:\cygwin\tmp\monobuild\build\BUILD\mono-2.6.7\mcs\class\System\System.Net\HttpWebRequest.cs:825
```

The bit of code causing this issue is:

```
string url = "http://webFarm/config.prop"; 
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url); 
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

It failed immediately. But if I switch the setting to "Default Runtime" instead of "Mono 2.10.2", everything is OK. Could anyone help me with this?

Regards,
David

Comment: I'd guess that 'Default Runtime' on Windows means MS.Net. Is the address http://webFarm/config.prop reachable with a normal browser?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes it is reachable. And as I mentioned, using 'Default Runtime', we did get the expected result. This application was originally coded under windows.

Comment: Have you tried to change the timeouts in `app.config` to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting this error using the code:

```
HttpWebRequest objRequest = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
objRequest.Timeout =15000;
objRequest.Method = "POST";
objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new 
    StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            myWriter.Write(strPost);
```

causes exception at GetRequestStream() :

```
System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x0005f] in 
/usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:752
  at NVPAPICaller.HttpCall (System.String NvpRequest) [0x00000] in <filename
```

unknown>:0

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.2 (tarball Mon Apr 18
```

18:57:39 UTC 2011); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433

You should revert back to older Mono 2.10 ,  2.10.1 will probably work.